# Is there a way to remove brackets and parenthesis from a set of tuples?

Tags: python

Is there a way to remove brackets and parenthesis from a set of tuples to achieve the desired printout? I have tried using * and sep but it does not seem to work.

```
result = {(1,2), (3,4)}
print(*result, sep = '\n')

desired printout:
1 2
3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in result:
    print(' '.join(str(j) for j in x))
```